# Creating a URL for JSON parsing on Android

Tags: php, android, json, parsing, url

This can be a silly question but can anyone tell me how can i create a url to parse ? I know json parsing on android from an existing url just like this >> http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/
 but i dont know how to create a url like this . Any suggestion ?

Comment: Umm, you need to create an API, or at least a page that respond using JSON format, actually you can send a JSON format response using almost any language nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check json_encode(): http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thank you , this is very helpful .I have another question . When i finished the php code , what should i do to have a url ? How can i have my own url , or website , or what is needed ? How can i load my codes to a url ? I have no php or website knowledge , i am not experienced on these stages.

Comment: Well, you should buy a web hosting and a domain to get that (or if you are testing, you could get a free domain name and a free web hosting).

Comment: When i am done with testing and decide to release my app on Google Market , will free hosting be a problem ? Is there a limit like that ?

Comment: No, it should not be a problem, but I use to trust more on servers I paid than free ones. A Free domain is more likely to disappear, suspend your account or be down rather than a paid one. It could also happen in a paid server, but is less probable.